# How to use sympy solve in for loop

Tags: python, sympy

I'm using sympy to solve an equation in a for loop in which at each interaction a variable (kp) multiples the function. But in each interaction the length of the output increases. I have an array k and kp is selected from k

```
k = [2,4,5,7,9]
for kp in k:
    didt = beta * kp * teta
    dteta = integrate(1/((kp-1) * pk * didt / avgk),teta)
    dt = integrate(1,(t,0 ,1))
    teta2 = solve(dteta - dt ,teta)
    #print(solve(dteta - dt ,teta))
    didt2 = beta *  solve(dteta - dt ,teta) *kp
    print(didt2)
```

Also, the output for didt2 for 1st iteration is
[1.49182469764127, 1.49182469764127]
for the second one is
[11.0231763806416, 11.0231763806416, 11.0231763806416, 11.0231763806416]
for the 3rd one is [54.5981500331442, 54.5981500331442, 54.5981500331442, 54.5981500331442, 54.5981500331442]
I'm just wondering, why the length of didt2 increases at each interaction?

Comment: What is the value of `teta2` on each iteration?

Comment: Side note: you can change `didt2 = beta *  solve(dteta - dt ,teta) *kp` to `didt2 = beta * teta2 * kp`.

Comment: 1st iteration teta2= [1.49182469764127], second iteration teta2 = [11.0231763806416] and 3rd iteration teta2 = [54.5981500331442]

Comment: Is it a list or a numpy array? And what are the values of `beta` and `kp` on each iteration?

Comment: teta2 is the output of solve() I haven't predefined. =. beta is a constant value equal to 1 and kp is selected from array k. the first two lines of the code

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `solve()` returns a list. This means that `beta *  solve(dteta - dt ,teta) *kp` doesn't do what you think. Rather than multiplying the result, you are duplicating the elements of the returned list. For a simple example, try to see what the output is:

```
[0] * 10
```

In your case, `kp` takes on the values of `2`, `4`, and `5` on each iteration of the list, so the output you see is the result of doing

```
[1.49182469764127] * 2
[11.0231763806416] * 4
[54.5981500331442] * 5
```

These all result in lists with the exact length of the value of `kp`. It does **not** do numeric multiplication.

Comment: Do you have any idea about what should I do? I want to solve an integration equation?

Comment: @Zahra That entirely depends on what you want the result to be? What are you trying to do here?

Comment: @Zahra Also, is the equation you are solving linear? Does it always only have one solution? Or can it have multiple solutions?

Comment: I want to solve multi integration equations. Their only difference is the value of kp

Comment: ok, `solve(dteta - dt ,teta)` already does that on its own. What are you trying to do with `beta * solve(dteta - dt ,teta) * kp`?